# Picard's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a version of Picard's theorem could hold in the unit disc?
Picard's theorem is that every transcendental entire function takes every value with at most one exception infinitely many times.

Also, what could we say about a polynomial P(z)=a_0+...+a_Nz^N and the function exp((z+1)/(z-1)) in the unit disc. What are the values of (z+1)/(z-1) for z in the unit disc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems doubtful. Even if we know that the function doesn't extend across any boundary point, it may still be bounded on the unit disc.

(Take for example something like $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^{n!}}{n^2}$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but could you explain more. I'm not fully understanding the theorem.